# How will Article 13 (EU) impact content on the Stack Exchange network?

Tags: discussion, code, licensing

As you hopefully know, in a few weeks, EU Parliament will vote for new copyright laws.

These new laws/directives (especially its most controversial component, Article 13) (Julia Reda shared the unofficial text [here](https://juliareda.eu/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/Art_13_unofficial.pdf)) will change the whole internet as we know today.
It would require online platforms to filter or remove all copyrighted material from their websites (during the upload!).  With Article 13, the online platforms and aggregator sites are now liable for copyright infringement.

How will the network handle these legal directives when ratified, and how will the network make sure no copyright protected content (code, images, text) is uploaded?

For reference:

[What is Article 13?](https://www.bbc.com/news/technology-47239600)

[What is Article 13 and how it will change copyright (on Twitch, with Co-Founder Emmett Shear)?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xEGBTAp-t5Y)

**Update**:
I read in the comments and in an answer:

> today, when you are posting content on Stack Overflow, you post it under the CC-By-SA license, which appears to be somewhat guarded against this

You should think differently. What would happen, when I post the Windows source code (as example), and the **platform** is now fully liable?
Same for all posted images (also the profile picture).

The problem is, the platform must ensure, that no copyright-protected material can be uploaded to the platform (when the platform does not have a licence **before** upload).

In Germany are many protests against Article 13, because this directive is not realizable. see https://savetheinternet.info/

Please see also [the second link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xEGBTAp-t5Y). It's a YouTube video with Twitch Co-Founder Emmett Shear, who talks about Article 13 and how it will affect the twitch-platform (and other platforms)

[**Update 2**]

Edward Snowden wrote about this:

> [In less than a month, the European Parliament will not only decide on a new #copyright law, but also on the future of the free and open #internet: If you are from the European Union, get active now, go to https://pledge2019.eu and ask your representative to #SaveYourInternet](https://twitter.com/Snowden/status/1103065119792250887).

Comment: Tim shared some of his considerations [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/311162/369403), boiling down to: we don't know. That's fair, since it hasn't even been voted upon, much less implemented. It's all hypothetical atm.

Comment: I guess we'll have to wait until it shows if SO is even targeted by article 13. The current definition is "a provider of an information society service whose main or one of the main purposes is to store and give the public access to a large amount of copyright protected works or other protected subject-matter uploaded by its users". I'm not a lawyer at all, so for me it's rather unclear if this includes SO or not. Especially because "open source software developing and sharing platforms" are explicitly excluded from the definition.

Comment: @BDL:  That would speak more to GitHub, not SO.  Stack Overflow is *very* much closed source and everything we post is licensed through CC-By-SA.

Comment: @Makoto Unless you explicitly license your code on GitHub under some open source license, you retain your full copyright by default [see](https://help.github.com/en/articles/licensing-a-repository)

Comment: If you posted someone else's property, that could get removed through the DMCA (which ain't going anywhere).  Considering that [Microsoft released MS-DOS as open-source](https://github.com/Microsoft/MS-DOS), the only real way any content provider would be able to deal with this circumstance is after the fact.  Now I'm not an EU resident, but I have no impression that this is realistically going to impact or change the networks in any discernible way, given the nature of how we have to deal with those instances.

Comment: Article 13 of what? Every EU directive has articles and there are _lots_ of directives.

Comment: @ErikA like brexit, people needs to plan before it gets implemented. How would affect the network needs to be tinkered upon and preparations be made.

Comment: @Braiam I wholly agree, but people don't need a plan _before it gets voted on_. If it gets accepted, which we'll likely know within several weeks, then we might need to start planning. Starting to plan right before it gets voted on is a bad plan: you gain little extra time, but still have a chance it's for nothing because it doesn't get voted in.

Comment: @ErikA do you know that the UE started preparations for a no deal brexit since the UK invoked article 50. UK hasn't done preparations for that scenario at all since they invoked said article. Who do you believe has the less possibilities of disruption? We should imitate UE behavior and be prepared for the worse case scenario.

Comment: @Braiam Try to think of it from a cost-benefit point of view: if we wait for the vote, we'll have the benefit of not wasting time on it if it doesn't go through, at the cost of a couple of weeks of prep time. That cost is likely negligible, since there's still substantial time between voting and preparation, and the benefit can be substantial. With Brexit, the cost is entirely different since the gap between decision and implementation is way smaller.

Comment: @ErikA When I said "started preparations", I didn't think of "implementing preparations", but "thinking about the possibilities and making action plans for the most likely". The later allows for adapting rapidly to changes in the environment. Companies that fail to adapt rapidly to changes in the environment, are those you never hear about.

Comment: "These new laws/directives ... will change the **whole internet** as we know today." The *whole internet*? No, there is a great deal of the internet that is outside the legal control and influence of the EU.

Answer (score 18):

Meh, I work at a HQ of a large multinational company that is in EU. It has been a topic here. The thing is: these politicians are not aware about the technological feasibility of enforcing these new copy right laws. They are not IT'ers like we are. They think that you can say to a computer that "*this image shall not be uploaded because it exists (partially) on site X*".

Try to explain the technological limitations of enforcing that rule in layman's terms. That is damn hard to do. There was a moment where I almost broke my bic (a pen) when trying to explain *why* that rule - despite that I do understand the need for it - is hard to implement to a lawyer.

Please be aware that the vote did not happen so far. And the next scheduled vote might be delayed due of Brexit / lobbying / ... It is just the uncertainty. That is not fun. It took a while when GDPR got voted. Fortunately, they gave companies time to comply the new regulations. The whole GDPR is a good thing IMO. Even if it has led to some annoys, technological problems, budget impact, ... Yet I have heard from a GDPR lawyer (got contracted to check the company) that there is a lot companies that are not in compliance with GDPR. That day was some weeks before the final deadline.

However - please don't read this as something that would happen - assume that Article 13 gets voted. It is possible to have a approach like this: A site owner provides a link (most companies have these anyways) where you, as a copyrighted owner of a content (via a patent or another legal document) want to see some content removed. And the site owner then clears it. That is what happens nowadays. Well, mostly. It has happened often that a large company (le Google or Facebook) refuses to remove content from their site, despite the copyright infringement. That article is just a legal means to protect a person more. This regulation gives him better tools to protect his - registered - creation. If yours request got denied, you can go to the court to issue an order to remove the content. Then the judge can order the removal. Possibility with a small fine. And a monetary value to pay back the victim (there is a specific term for it, but idk how it is worded in English). Yet that is often time consuming for both courts and the victim. Not to mention the cost. The victim does not always have money to "fight" against large companies that have a team of skilled lawyers at their appeal. Assume that Article 13 gets voted, then the victim has more chance of protection and the judge can order a huge fine, at a level that it really would hurt companies in their pocket. To "encourage" them to remove content if there are copyright infringements.

In essence, that article 13 is just for hurting large companies in a sensible spot: "their wallet". Courts can order a huge fine if eg Google refuses to remove some content.

Comment: *"Try to explain the technological limitations of enforcing that rule in layman's terms. That is damn hard to do."* So true. I work at a major European university and tried to explain our government partners why automatic content filtering is a technical challenge/problem. Don't think my point was understood.

Comment: People somehow stop at "Just don't let them post copyrighted content" without spending a second thinking about "How are you going to do that?"

Comment: @Magisch And that's the scary thing. They will expect companies to do exactly that and when it isn't done, they would point towards someone that does a botched attempt and impose fines. As long as there is a single example of someone doing it, however badly implemented, fines would be applied.

Comment: I can't imagine how you could create a copyrighted material filter.  Even if you had a catalog of every copyrighted picture ever produced, it would be awful hard to match the same picture that had been cropped, stretched and slightly photoshopped/filtered.  Even text is hard to match.  I did a graduate degree a few years back and the profs would run our papers through an anti-plagiarize site.  I was amazed that my papers would score 15-20%.  Every attributed quote would be flagged as would all of the references.

Comment: @Flydog57 You can't. Sounds like it's time for ACM to dust off [this letter it sent to Harry Reid](https://techpolicy.acm.org/2008/04/usacm-cautions-against-filtering/) (who was at that time the Senate Majority Leader in the U.S.) when he was trying to pass similarly idiotic legislation in the U.S. Thankfully, it failed.

Comment: My solution to explain it is to memorize a quote from a book. `“Zagreus sits inside your head,
Zagreus lives among the dead,
Zagreus sees you in your bed,
And eats you when you're sleeping.”` then I say, you have to block this sentence everywhere where you encounter it, it's copyrighted, even though you don't know where it's from or that it even existed. This sentence has copyright and must be blocked by the filter. Now come up with an idea how to get this blocked and I'll implement it. Then i'll try to upload the second paragraph of this copyrighted text ands see if your idea will block it

Comment: @Magisch relevant username, you answer your own question! Anyway, more seriously, @ KarelG, how does this answer the question? This isn't law.SE asking whether politicians are also "IT'ers" (hello fellow Dutch speaker :) ), but a meta.SE question asking "how does it affect SE".

Comment: Try to explain copyright law to general IT folks.  That is damn hard to do.  (I think that I'm allow to twist and repost KarelG's words under the "parody" exception.)

Comment: @CPerkins I think the generalization is "trying to explain something specialized to someone that isn't their specialization is damn hard to do".

Comment: I find it naive to think they really don't have a clue how hard this is to do. Any evidence?

Comment: Could also be the other way around: the article is for large companies to hurt small companies each time someone writes the word "Roomba" or post a picture of something remotely looking like the olympic rings.

Answer (score 13):

This seems ***quite*** alarmist...

From the BBC article you linked, the summation of the article is as thus.

> Article 13 says content-sharing services must license
> copyright-protected material from the rights holders.
>
> If that is not possible and material is posted on the service, the
> company may be held liable unless it can demonstrate:
>
> - it made "best efforts" to get permission from the copyright holder
> - it made "best efforts" to ensure that material specified by rights holders was not made available
> - it acted quickly to remove any infringing material of which it was made aware
>
> These rules apply to services that have been available in the EU for
> more than three years, or have an annual turnover of more than €10m
> (£8.8m, $11.2m).
>
> Article 13 says it shall "in no way affect legitimate uses" and people
> will be allowed to use bits of copyright-protected material for the
> purpose of criticism, review, parody and pastiche.

Effectively today, when you are posting content on Stack Overflow, you post it under the [CC-By-SA license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), which appears to be somewhat guarded against this.

> **No additional restrictions** — You may not apply legal terms or technological measures that legally restrict others from doing anything the license permits.

That'll have to be a matter which is settled by the EU courts, which Stack Overflow is beholden to (provided that Britain leaves the EU with a deal in place on the 29th, or if they don't leave at all - don't listen to an American talk about Brexit, read up on how it'll make laws like this weird for yourself).

Stack Overflow [already removes content via DMCA request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/317709/175248), so if you're *not* the copyright holder of a piece of work, the person who *is* can still take action against the content.

So I think this'll be a wait and see approach from the perspective of the layman.  It's an excellent legal question, but I don't think it's really too pertinent to worry about until after it's been voted and ratified in the EU.

Comment: Please see my updated question.

Comment: I'm worried that CC may not be enough to insulate SO of the effects of the implementation of this rule. Note that Creative Commons still [has misgivings about the leaked text](https://creativecommons.org/2019/02/18/eu-copyright-directive-moves-into-critical-final-stage/): "Article 13 will require nearly all for-profit web platforms that permit user uploads to install copyright filters and censor content." Thought they say "At least openly licensed works such as those under Creative Commons or in the public domain would be exempted. "

Comment: @Braiam: No third party has the right under any legal theory that I know of to usurp someone's copyrights by posting copyrighted material to a website like Stack Overflow.  Saying that this post is "alarmist" is an understatement.

Comment: @RobertHarvey The problem that they point out isn't that someone would usurp the copyright, they say "all for-profit" that allows "user uploads" (like Stack Overflow) should "install copyright filters and censor content". In other words, SO should prevent copyrighted material from ever being uploaded to the platform. The filter isn't for our copyrighted content, is to prevent us from uploading copyrighted content.

Comment: @Braiam: Or they can otherwise demonstrate that they "acted quickly to remove any infringing material of which it was made aware."  The whole "should install copyright filters and censor content" is a statement that the BBC made.  That's what we get for listening to the BBC.

Comment: @RobertHarvey:  I'm not a laywer, I'm an American passer-by who happened to notice some of the all-caps in the title before I edited it into *not* that, and had a chance to really think about all of the concepts here.  "Alarmist" is what immediately came to mind but I don't disagree with you here that this is an understatement.

Comment: From what I gather, this is the EU's version of the DMCA. That still means it should be opposed and destroyed with extreme prejudice, but it's not going to end the internet as we know it.

Comment: @RobertHarvey wait, right now I'm quoting CreativeCommons. I presume they have the copyright lawyers that allows them to analyze from the legal standpoint, the ramifications of the leaked wording. I'm not quoting the BBC article at all.

Comment: @Braiam: Creative Commons *does not* provide a loophole for some third party to usurp a copyright holder's rights.  Full stop.

Comment: I love when bureaucrats say things like "[it shall] in no way affect legitimate uses" and "people will be allowed to use bits of copyright-protected material for the purpose of criticism, review, parody and pastiche." Like, ok, well they said that the rule wouldn't cause any problems, so I totally trust you!!!

Comment: @RobertHarvey again I'm not speaking about "usurp a copyright holder's right". Full stop. Stop trying to twist my concerns into it. I'm talking about how Stack Overflow would prevent copyrighted works from being uploaded, as the leaked text of the Article 13 specifies.

Comment: @Braiam: And I'm talking about the motivations for preventing such copyrighted works from being uploaded.  I haven't read the law, but so far I haven't seen anything that actually *requires* websites to preemptively prevent people from uploading copyrighted content, only that such uploads be dealt with swiftly.

Comment: @RobertHarvey https://juliareda.eu/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/Art_13_unofficial.pdf That's the unofficial text (unofficial because it hasn't been approved).

Comment: (Off topic, but to respond to your parenthetic statement - Don't you think having a legislature over your parliament, and a government over the British government is going to be weird?  The EU is a trade organization that covertly became a government.)

Answer (score -7):

In addition to the whole question of what the law will cover, it's worth mentioning that since the nature of Stack Overflow means that it is not really going to impact on content creators in the same way as youtube for example,  even if the worst-case scenario occurs it is fairly unlikely that a company would pursue it in the aggressive way that video and music sharing platforms might be.

Comment: Really? SCO [bankrupted itself](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SCO%E2%80%93Linux_disputes) over copyright. Microsoft [invoked the FBI](https://news.microsoft.com/2004/02/12/statement-from-microsoft-regarding-illegal-posting-of-windows-2000-source-code/) when NT code leaked. Then there's [Cisco, and Zenimax, and others](https://www.copyrightcontentplatforms.com/2018/01/2017-the-year-in-which-copyright-went-beyond-source-code). The [lengths closed source owners will go](https://www.bakerlaw.com/BeyondSourceCode) may surprise you.